# Microsoft Graph API account mailbox settings mail auto forwarding

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365

Is there any way to get the mailbox auto forwarding settings? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-automatic-forwarding-in-outlook-on-the-web-7f2670a1-7fff-4475-8a3c-5822d63b0c8e

Seems like its not available here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
Any other way?

Answer (score 1):

MS Graph API doesn't yet support setting mailbox auto forwarding. In the case you have an on-premises Exchange or an instance in the cloud-based service you can leverage the  ExchangePowerShell Module using [Set-Mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) cmdlet where you can set the forwarding address.

Comment: Is there still no MS Graph API to do this 2 years later? I'm looking to do the same thing and would rather keep with MS Graph API vs rigging in Powershell into our Intranet site.